# `console.log` and `alert` not working in Vite Laravel 10 app

Tags: javascript, laravel, vite

I'm currently working on a Vite Laravel 10 app and I'm facing an issue where both `console.log` and `alert` statements are not working.

I have the following code in my `resources/js/app.js

```
alert("hi");
console.log("hi");
import "./bootstrap";
```

I expect to see the alert dialog and the message "hi" logged to the browser's console. However, neither of them are displaying any output.

**Environment Details:**

- Operating System: WSL Ubuntu
- PHP Version: 8.1.2
- Laravel Framework Version: 10.15.0
- Vite Version: 4.4.3

**Troubleshooting Steps Taken:**

- Checked that the code is correctly placed in the `resources/js/app.js` file.
- Verified that the `bootstrap` module is imported correctly.
- Tried using both `console.log` and `alert` statements in different parts of my code.
- Changed browsers to see if the issue persists.
- Ensured that there are no filters applied in the Chrome console.
- Checked all levels of output (verbose, info, warnings, errors) in the Chrome console.
- Executed the `npm run dev` command to start the development server.

Despite these attempts, I'm still unable to see the alert dialog or the message "hi" logged to the browser's console.

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue. Thank you!

Comment: make sure you have linked your app.js properly file in your view file

Comment: i forgot to link the file so i added a line "@vite('resources/js/app.js')" at the bottom of head.
But theres no console.log("hi"); in compiled version of app.js.

Comment: I changed the way link app.js to <script src="{{ asset('build/assets/app-a4d2d3c1.js') }}" defer></script> and it worked, however i dont why @vite didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I restarted my computer, every problem has gone...
@vite(['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'])
works as expected and I can see the console.log and alert.

Answer (score 1):

Set a `debugger;` in your app js file, Then run your app. I think your app js file is not running.

**Note: open the console panel when you are running your app.**

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your main laravel file:

```
@vite(['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'])
```